# How to solve "failed to execute goal "maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1" in maven

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

Im tryig to get a simple valid login test build in maven to later run in a jenkins server.

The thing is: everytime I build (clean install) i get the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test (default-test) on project validLogin: There are test failures.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please refer to C:\Users\Me\workspace\validLogin\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

I litteraly losing my hair here, how to fix this? (the error not the hair)

Comment: Some issue with your test cases, to skip you can try  "mvn -DskipTests clean install"

Comment: To further debug the issue with test cases run   "mvn -X clean install"

Comment: Im trying this now with some hope in my heart

Comment: @ravthiru thanks, I tried before that mvn - X clean install, but same results :(

Comment: IT WORKED FROM MY PROMPT, THANKS SO MUCH!

the build is successful. does it mean the tests are running normal in order to detect issues? Im moving it now to my jenkins server.
thanks again :D

Comment: -DskipTests, will not run the test cases

Comment: Ohhh I see @ravthiru
would you know why I'm getting this error? I tried other version of this dependency but still same results

Comment: There is no problem with your sure fire dependency. The tests themselves are failing. You will need to look at the failing tests to get the build to work when running tests.

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
mvn clean install -DskipTests
```

Instead to skip tests if you don't want them to be executed.

Answer (score 2):

There are failing tests for your build which need to be fixed. To see *which* tests are failing, In the surefire plugin configuration section of your pom.xml, check that the printSummary option is set to **true**.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19</version>
            <configuration>
                <printSummary>true</printSummary>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Once this option is set, you should see the full list of test results (including failures) in your command-line output.

The test failures are also listed inside ***C:\Users\Me\workspace\validLogin\target\surefire-reports***

Comment: What I do not understand is why the tests run fine in firefox in my local but they dont when I use htmlunitdriver, which I need since the tests are meant to a headless server on amazon

Comment: Now that is a separate question altogether :). Do you know which test is failing and where? It might be worth creating a separate question for that. Ideally, if you can post snippets of code where the problem is, then it helps SOers to figure out what the problem might be _and_ also shows that you have done your homework :)