# Error when trying to deploy to AZURE Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test

Tags: java, spring, azure, maven, deployment

**Hi developers friends I need help please When I try to deploy from github to my Azure AppService the github console shows me the following error.**

Hi developers friends I need help please When I try to deploy from github to my Azure AppService the github console shows me the following error.

Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test (default-test) on project FastFoodApp: There are test failures.

Please refer to /home/runner/work/Project-Name/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results. Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date].dump, [date]-jvmRun[N].dump and [date].dumpstream. -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch. Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

**I already tried adding mvn clean install -DskipTests in the .yml file. Also adding in the pom.xml file**

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Also

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
            <configuration>
            <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
            </configuration>
</plugin>
```

**Also I tried commenting out all code in src/test/java -> test.java**

But in the end it always shows me the same error

this is the .yml file

```
name: Build and deploy JAR app to Azure Web App - fastfoodapi

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up Java version
        uses: actions/setup-java@v1
        with:
          java-version: '11'

      - name: Build with Maven
        run: mvn clean install

      - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: java-app
          path: '${{ github.workspace }}/target/*.jar'

  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}
    
    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: java-app

      - name: Deploy to Azure Web App
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        with:
          app-name: 'fastfoodapi'
          slot-name: 'Production'
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_PUBLISHPROFILE_2896B985447E4F1D85D4FE3ECA3795AC }}
          package: '*.jar'
```

Comment: Check the code of the test which is failing... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following steps to resolve the error:

- Right Click on project **>** Run as Maven Test.
- The missing plugin will be downloaded automatically.
- Right Click on project **>** Update Maven project, after that the error should be gone.

**References:**

1. [Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test" and "test(s) <[]> cannot be found"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42168610/after-upgrading-getting-failed-to-execute-goal-org-apache-maven-pluginsmaven)
2. [How to solve "failed to execute goal "maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1" in maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40229895/how-to-solve-failed-to-execute-goal-maven-surefire-plugin2-19-1-in-maven)
3. [Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31221182/failed-to-execute-goal-org-apache-maven-pluginsmaven-surefire-plugin2-18-1tes)
4. [Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.10:test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13170860/failed-to-execute-goal-org-apache-maven-pluginsmaven-surefire-plugin2-10test)

Comment: It is a very strange error, because I did what you told me long before but it did not work. as I mentioned I was trying to upload it to azure with a database that is also in azure, I had to leave it Public access (allowed IP addresses) the Connectivity method.